# Conflicting GSON libs

Tags: android, millennial-media

In our app we use the GSON.JAR lib. And now we have updated the Millennial media to version 5. With thie new version of MMEDIA they only give the JAR package and in their package they also use the GSON lib. So it now conflicts with our lib.

```
Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gson/JsonSerializer;
```

Possible solution would be if we deleted our GSON lib so it would only use the Millennial Media's GSON lib.

Is there another solution, because we really do not want to delete our GSON lib file and be dependend on the Millennial Medias GSON lib as there is no telling what they could have changed there.

Comment: remove GSON lib, since it is already inside MMEDIA jar

Comment: please reread the last paragraph

Comment: out of all questions, why can not use the native android JSon library? Unfortunally there I do not know any solution for the Multiple dex error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Millennial is actually fixing this for the SDK 5.0.1 release (which is due out next week pending some additional quality assurance) by renaming the internal GSON library. The Millennial SDK uses GSON version 2.2.2 unmodified. You can either use the GSON within the MMSDK.jar or, if absolutely necessary, unjaring Millennial's JAR and removing the "com/google/gson/" directory and re-jaring it.

As usual, you can also talk to Millennial directly at: https://tools.mmedia.com/user/supportDevPortal