# about Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gson/JsonSerializer

Tags: android, testing, exception, shared-libraries

I have a problem. When building the project I encounter this:

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gson/JsonSerializer;

When I check my jar files in pre-dexed folder, I found two gson one is 2.2.2 and one is 2.3.1.

I try to find where those gson from and I sadly found that those two are from :

1. spoon-runner;
2. alipay.jar;

I think those gson are internal files inside the jar I list before.

Any one have ideas?

Comment: How did you find where they were from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the GSON within the MMSDK.jar or, if absolutely necessary, unjaring Millennial's JAR and removing the "com/google/gson/" directory and re-jaring it.

You may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584709/conflicting-gson-libs) for more info